# Dependent dropdownlist with chosen jquery plugin. Dynamic update

Tags: yii, yii-components

I'm new to yii so dont be strict.
I have dependent dropdown list with countries/states from model. It works perfect until comes Chosen jquery plugin.
I use http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/.
So the problem is in howto trigger liszt:updated, so 2nd select can obtain data from standart select.
This is view code which makes that lists.

```
if ($field->varname=='country') {
        echo $form->dropDownList($profile, $field->varname,CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(),'short','title'), array(
        'class'=>"chzn-select",
        'empty'=>"Select country",  
        'ajax' => array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'url'=>$this->createUrl('registration/state'),   
                        'update' => '#Profile_state',                        
                        'data'=>array('country'=>'js:this.value',),     

        )));

        }

        elseif($field->varname=='state') {
        echo $form->dropDownList($profile, $field->varname,array(), array(
        'empty'=>"Select state",
        'class'=>"chzn-select",

        ));
```

Comment: Where is your `<div id=Profile_state></div>`???

Comment: Its not div its container for select.

Comment: `<select class="chzn-select chzn-done" name="Profile[state]" id="Profile_state" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Select state</option>
</select>`

Comment: The most obvious solution to add success call to ajax `'success'=>'function(){$("#Profile_state").trigger("liszt:updated");}'`. But this dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. Writing it here(maybe someone will find it usefull).
In our view file

```
echo $form->dropDownList($profile, $field->varname,CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(),'short','title'), array(
        'class'=>"chzn-select",
        'empty'=>"Select country",  
        'ajax' => array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'url'=>$this->createUrl('registration/state'),   
                        'update' => '#Profile_state',                        
                        'data'=>array('country'=>'js:this.value',), 
                        'success'=> 'function(data) {
                                        $("#Profile_state").empty();
                                        $("#Profile_state").append(data);
                                        $("#Profile_state").trigger("liszt:updated");

                                                } ',

        )));
```

Then in 2nd dropdownlist leve data empty:

```
echo $form->dropDownlist($profile, $field->varname, array(),array(
    'class'=>"chzn-select",
    'empty'=>"Select state",
    ));
```

Works perfect for me but gave me hours of research work.